I want a set 'var' to be used in a replace.bodytext string
I have a cell that has both the first and last name together "Autumn Smith"
In a document my code auto fills, the name is listed many times. I would like the first time the name is mentioned to be both the first and last name but then only the first name throughout the rest of the document - "Autumn"
I have a var set to separate names and now I would like to use that var to plug in only the first name.
This is the var code I have in place currently:
 var fullName = row[3];
 var bothNames = fullName.split(" ");
 var firstName = bothNames[0];
 var lastName = bothNames[1];
 var abbreviatedName = firstName.substring(0, 1) + ". " + lastName;

and the replacement code I have is:
body.replaceText(`{{Name1}}`, firstName (row[3]));

When I run the code in AppsScript, no errors generate.
When I try to actually utilize the generator, I receive an error stating "firstName is not a function"
I'm very new to coding and am not quite sure what I am missing

First Name is  a string not a function.  You were using it like a function
This worked for me
function myfunk() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(gobj.globals.testdocid);
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const row = ["zero","one","two","Howard Hughs"]
  var fullName = row[3];
  var bothNames = fullName.split(" ");
  var firstName = bothNames[0];
  var lastName = bothNames[1];
  var abbreviatedName = firstName.slice(0, 1) + ". " + lastName;
  body.replaceText(`{{Name1}}`, abbreviatedName);
}

